# Get test execution logs during test run by Nunit Test Engine

Tags: nunit

We are using NUnit Test Engine to run test programatically.
Lokks like that after we add [FrameworkPackageSettings.NumberOfTestWorkers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74316773/no-possbile-to-set-workers-via-nunit-engine-api) to the Runner code, the test run for our Ui test hangs in execution. I'm not able to see at what time or event the execuiton hangs because Test Runned returns test result logs (in xml) only when entire execution ends

Is there a way to get test execution logs for each test?

I've added InternalTraceLevel and InternalTraceWriter but these logs are something different (BTW, looks like ParallelWorker#9 hangs even to write to console :) [image])

```
_package.AddSetting(FrameworkPackageSettings.InternalTraceLevel, "Debug");
var nunitInternalLogsPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath)) + "\\NunitInternalLogs.txt";
Console.WriteLine("nunitInternalLogsPath: "+nunitInternalLogsPath);
StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(nunitInternalLogsPath);
_package.AddSetting(FrameworkPackageSettings.InternalTraceWriter, writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result file, with default name `TestResult.xml` is not a log. That is, it is not a file produced, line by line, as execution proceeds. Rather, it is a picture of the result of your entire run and therefore is only created at the end of the run.

**InternalTrace** logs are actual logs in that sense. They were created to allow us to debug the internal workings of NUnit. We often ask users to create them when an NUnit bug is being tracked. Up to four of them may be produced when running a test of a single assembly under nunit3-console...

1. A log of the console runner itself
2. A log of the engine.
3. A log of the agent used to run tests (if an agent is used)
4. A log received from the test framework running the tests

In your case, #1 is not produced, of course. Based on the content of the trace log, we are seeing #4, triggered by the package setting passed to the framework. I have seen the situation where the log is incomplete in the past but not recently. The logs normally use auto-flush to ensure that all output is actually written.

If you want to see a complete log #2, then set the WorkDirectory and InternalTrace properties of the engine when you create it.

---

**However**, as stated, these logs are all intended for debugging NUnit, not for debugging your tests. The console runner produces another "log" even though it isn't given that name. It's the output written to the console as the tests run, especially that produced when using the --labels option.

If you want some similar information from your own runner, I suggest producing it yourself. Create either console output or a log file of some kind, by processing the various events received from the tests as they execute. To get an idea of how to do this, I suggest examining the code of the NUnit3 console runner. In particular, take a look at the `TestEventHandler` class, found at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/version3/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/TestEventHandler.cs